# Checking the content of a list of files against a list of words in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to check the content of a list of files (wfiles) against a list of words (ylist), and then print the names of the files and some confirmation if a word in ylist was found.

This is wfiles:

```
wfiles = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
```

This is the content of a.txt:

```
hello jim this is tom 
the serial code: x029-1029-2031
the password is bananaappleorange. grapes
cheer for the grapes 
regards, tom
```

This is the content of b.txt:

```
this is a test not a joke, though I'm kidding.
lambda is firthy 23 too.
```

This is the content of c.txt:

```
is
not
here
xyz
069
@heytheremate. this is your friend. how are you?
```

To deal with this I have:

```
something = 'myfolder'
ylist = ['grapes', 'name']
dmd = os.listdir(something)
wfiles = []
for i in dmd:
    if ".txt" in i:
        wfiles.append(item)

for w in wfiles:
    with open(something + '/' + w) as ofiles:
        for xlist in ofiles:
            if any(word in xlist for word in ylist):
                print w, 'FOUND'
                break;
            else:
                print w, 'NOTFOUND'
                break;
```

Notably in the instance of a.txt, 'grapes' and 'name' are both present (from ylist) and should print 'FOUND', however in the instances of b.txt and c.text, of which do not include another of those words, also had 'FOUND' printed out when 'NOTFOUND' should've been printed in their cases.

This is what I received after running the code:

```
a.txt FOUND
b.txt FOUND
c.txt FOUND
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: shouldent you add `file.read()` somewhere in there?

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
with open(w) as ofiles:
```

`open(w)` returns a file object. I think you need:

```
for xlist in ofiles.read().split():
```

to get the words in the file.

here is your code revised - works for me (for your three files):

```
>>> for w in wfiles:
...     with open(w) as ofiles:
...             if any(word in ofiles.read().split() for word in ylist):
...                     print w,'found'
... 
a.txt found
```

Comment: Strangely the output remains the same. Inserting `print xlist` under `for xlist in ofiles.read().split():` I found that it was just grabbing the first word in each .txt file.

Comment: yes, this for iterates over single words. If you want to keep the code as it is change this line : `if any(word in xlist for word in ylist):` to `if any(word in xlist.read().split() for word in ylist):`

Comment: That seems to be right. Oddly enough 'FOUND' is still printed for all three files.

Comment: Added them to the question now.

Comment: Strangely the output's the same for me, though likely because of the code I left omitted that definitely should not have been. Added it in now, can you see anything that may be affecting me from not receiving the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

```
wfiles = ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']
ylist = ['grapes', 'name']

for w in wfiles:
    with open(w) as ofiles:
        if any(word in ofiles.read().split() for word in ylist):
            print "Found"
        else:
            print "Not Found"
```

You can use file read() with all the words in a file. As per your code, you get always the first line and if the list of words not matched in the first line, you break.-

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Strangely however "Found" is being printed for all three files, any idea why?

Comment: yes..now this implementation works based on individual files...you can edit `print "Found in",w` to identify in which file those keys are found.

Comment: Received `Found in a.txt ... Found in c.txt'`, three lines printed in total (one for each file). This is what I used (`print w, 'FOUND'`) in the question (I'll go add an example of the output now).

Comment: donot you have 'grapes' or 'name' in b.txt and c.txt?

Comment: Neither are present in them; both files have their content included in the question now.

Comment: I tested my code in python2.7 and it works as exepected (prints Found for first file and "not found" for second and third files).

Comment: Strangely the same for me, though likely because of the code I left omitted that definitely should not have been. Added it in now, can you see anything that may be affecting me from not receiving the correct output?

Comment: You suppose to get "NOT FOUND" in all three as you are checking only the first line from each file.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not receiving that (absolutely no idea why).

Answer (score 0):

This would help you:

```
wfiles = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']                                        
ylist = ['grapes', 'name']                                                  

for w in wfiles:                                                            
    with open(w) as ofiles:                                                 
        content = ofiles.read()                                             
        if any(word in content for word in ylist):                          
            print w, 'FOUND'                                                
        else:                                                               
            print w, 'NOTFOUND'
```

This works for me:

```
import os                                                                      
something = '.'                                                                
ylist = ['grapes', 'name']                                                     
dmd = os.listdir(something)                                                    
wfiles = []                                                                    
for item in dmd:                                                               
    if ".txt" in item:                                                         
        wfiles.append(item)                                                    

for w in wfiles:                                                               
    with open(something + '/' + w) as ofiles:                                  
        content = ofiles.read()                                                
        if any(word in content for word in ylist):                             
            print w, 'FOUND'                                                   
        else:                                                                  
            print w, 'NOTFOUND'
```

If you still get unexpected result, please check if your script open the right file you expected.

Comment: Strangely 'FOUND' is still printed out for all three files (tried using both of your examples).

Comment: Can you post your b.txt for reference?

Comment: Strangely the same for me, though likely because of the code I left omitted that definitely should not have been. Added it in now, can you see anything that may be affecting me from not receiving the correct output?